# Regex - unknown place of character

Tags: regex

I have a string like as `abcd` but the place of `a` is unknown. The string can be `bacd` or `bcad` or `bcda`.

I tried

```
a{0,1}ba{0,1}ca{0,1}da{0,1}
```

but this pattern matches `bcd` too.

I need exactly one occurrence of `a` with unknown place.
`a` is a symbol. Iwant to use sth like as `b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]` Instead of `a`.

Comment: Please specify a language as per the [tag:regex] tag.

Comment: So your string can be any length long? Can your set of symbols intrsect with b or c or d? Can a be b or c or d? Can b c d repeat? Elaborate please

Answer (score 1):

Your criteria seem to be:

- `bcd` all appear once and in that order
- `a` appears once anywhere (and "a" is a placeholder for a complex expression)
- no other chars

This will do it:

```
^(?!bcd$)(?!(.*a){2})(a)?b(a)?c(a)?d(a)?$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/IVTcIn3rxL).

The look-aheads ensure there is exactly one `a`, and "a" can be a complete expression.

Note also the use of `?` instead of `{0,1}`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works correctly. But `a` is a symbol. I want to use for example `b[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f]` instead of `a`. But it does not work.

Comment: @MohammadRezaRamezani, elaborate on your question in the question. Show what you want, posible cases

Comment: @moh I have changed the regex so you can replace "a" with your complex expression and it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer

> abcd|bacd|bcad|bcda

Perfectly readable, good performance, and works everywhere.

Longer answer.

Regular expression should not be used too hackly. It is a state machine and will run slow if you make it too complex.

When time you need to while a small function, write that function.

> a?ba?ca?da?  -- with a following up function to count the number of a.

Comment: It is clear. Reread the question. Also your pattern matches `bcd`, he wants `a` to be there.

Comment: Thanks but `abcd` is symbolic items. I have to use complex string instead of them. `abcd` is long enough and I can not repeat them for times.

Comment: If it is just long, you can program to build that repeating string. RegEx (and also SQL) is a good fit for something but not everything.

Answer (score -1):

This answer builds on Dennis Cheung's answer, and is written in `java` (You did not specify a language)

```
string.replaceAll("a", "").matches("bcd") &&
string.replaceAll("[^a]", "").equals("a") &&
string.matches("a?ba?ca?da?")
```